# Why is state not updated even after loading is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple loading component.
I want to update a state after all Dom has finished loading.
And I want to change the display of child elements.
But it doesn't work. Why..

- Parent

```js
//Page.js

class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loading isLoaded={this.state.isLoaded} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Page;
```

- Child

```js
//Loading.js

class Loading extends Component {
  loading = null;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props); // {isLoaded: false}
    this.isLoaded = props.isLoaded;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.loader_area} aria-hidden={this.isLoaded}>
          <div className={styles.loader} aria-hidden={this.isLoaded} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Loading;
```

Comment: when Loading is first loaded, isLoaded is false. you need to listen to props update with either hooks or getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: You only set `this.isLoaded` once and never change it afterwards. You need to use `this.props.isLoaded` instead.

Comment: your sandbox is 'empty'.

Comment: @GuyIncognito. You detect some errors, but I don't understand your comment. ```this.props.isLoaded``` is correct because the values is passed from the parent.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice I don't understand your comment? Yes, `this.props.isLoaded` is correct like I said. The OP doesn't use that which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `contructor` in class component is just initiated only one time in the first rendering. So it will not update `props` inside the constructor. But I think you should use `this.props.isLoaded` instead of using `this.isLoaded` to store props value. 
Try this:

```js
class Loading extends Component {
  loading = null;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.loader_area} aria-hidden={this.props.isLoaded}>
          <div className={styles.loader} aria-hidden={this.props.isLoaded} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Loading;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand.
But the above code gives a warning.
"Useless constructor"

Comment: Can I delete the constructor?

Comment: @y2UcDgAL Yes, you can

Answer (score 0):

I could receive props.

```js
class Loading extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.loader_area} aria-hidden={this.props.isLoaded}>
          <div className={styles.loader} aria-hidden={this.props.isLoaded}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Loading;
```